# Which wallets or services currently support OpenAlias?

Tags: address, openalias

Are there any wallets or services that support OpenAlias formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official CLI and GUI IIRC, and latest monerujo 1.7.3 beta.

Answer (score 0):

The chrome extension blockchain gateway parses the Open Alias urls:

Chrome Extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/blockchain-gateway/mcppmdjlghmadabjofodajpppiloembp

Web URL: https://www.xcubicle.com/blockchain-gateway-btc-eth-xmr-openalias-domain

```
The Open Alias (openalias.org) handler is also supported: OA:// OPENALIAS://
```

After installing the chrome extention, it renders the following formats:

oa://donate.getmonero.org

openalias://openalias.org